# Strange behaviour of match-string/string-match

Tags: string, match-data

I have this code

```
(defun string-match-test ()
  (interactive)
  (string-match "12345" (buffer-string))
  (setq STRING (match-string 0))
  (read-string STRING)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (insert STRING)
  )

(string-match-test)
```

I expected it to print `12345` but I get, instead `"1234`. What's my mistake? May I have misunderstood the `buffer-string` function behaviour?

**Note.** I kwow I can use `serch-forward-regexp` combined with `with-temp-buffer`... but I'd like to understand the reason of this weird behaviur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation of `match-string`.  It contains:

```
(match-string NUM &optional STRING)
...
STRING should be given if the last search was by ‘string-match’ on STRING.
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I thought that the current buffer and the `buffer-string` output was the same thing/string.

Comment: Yeah! So much to discover and learn. Same here. ;)